# Blue Pelican Add 'Em Up Project

Tags: java

I've been working on the Blue Pelican Java project called Add 'Em Up for several hours now, and I can't figure out how to get it to work. The project description is this:

Consider the following program that allows something like 8 + 33 + 1,345 +137 to be entered as
String input from the keyboard. A Scanner object then uses the plus signs (and any adjoining
whitespace) as delimiters and produces the sum of these numbers(1523).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Tester
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1,345 +137 : ");
String s = kb.nextLine( );
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\+\\s*");
int sum = 0;
while(sc.hasNextInt( ))
{
sum = sum + sc.nextInt( );
}
System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
}
}
```

The output will typically look like this:
Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1,345 +137 : 8 + 33 + 1,345 + 137
Sum is: 1523
Now modify this program so as to allow either plus or minus signs. Don’t forget to allow for a
leading plus or minus sign on the first number in the sequence. If the leading number has no sign,
assume the number is positive. Your output should typically appear as follows:
Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1,345 -137 : 8 + 33+ 1,345 -137
Sum is: 1249

The code below is what I currently have. The program works just fine for adding numbers, but for some reason the subtraction isn't working. For example, if you enter 5-2, the answer comes out as -7 instead of 3.

```
public class AddEmUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137 : ");
        String s = kb.nextLine();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
        int sum = 0;

        if (s.contains("+")) {
            sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\+\\s*");
            while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                sum = sum + sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        if (s.contains("-")) {
            sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\-\\s*");
            while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                sum = sum - sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
    }
```

Any help on what I should be trying to do in order to fix this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subtraction case is going to require a little more work than addition in this code! I think once you understand what is happening, you'll see how you need to adjust your strategy.

This is what is happening right now with the input 5 - 2.

```
int sum = 0
s.contains("-") is true.
sum = sum - sc.nextInt() occurs,
Remember at the top of your code sum was set to zero!
so sum = 0 - 5

Now sum = -5.
s.contains("-") is true.
sum = sum - sc.nextInt() occurs
sum = -5 - 2.

At the end of your program, sum = -7.
```

You are going to need to restructure the logic of your program a bit. Right now, the first thing you check is to see if there is either a '+' or a '-' symbol in your input. If there is a '+' symbol, you start from sum=0 and add every number you see. This works pretty well for addition, and you'll always get the right answer. If there is a '-' symbol, you start from sum=0 and subtract every number you see. That's not quite the intention with subtraction though. In the case of 5 - 2, what you would rather do is from sum=0 '+ 5' and then '- 3'.

Your code is fine in the sense that it compiles and runs - what you have here is what is known as a 'logic bug'. The steps that you have asked the program to do are not the same as the actual steps you want it to do. Give careful thought to what is happening at each point of your program to make sure that it behaves correctly.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! I was able to figure out what needed to be changed.